# Printer Friendly Web Page

Tags: html, css

I wish to let client to have a pretty print page from a web page.

Hence, I change the following line from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen"/>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print"/>
```

The content of screen.css and print.css are the same.

However, for `print` version, I realize all my CSS style had gone. Table color, padding, margin, font... all gone. and when I view under FireBug, it seems there is no style.

May I know anything I had missed out?

**print.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>

<div class="main-title">Worksheet</div>               

<div class="header-table-container">
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>House Address</th>
    <td>33, Robinson Road.</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="main-table-container">
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th width="10%" rowspan="2">Parts</th>
    <th width="90%" colspan="4">Doraemon</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <th width="25%">Trial 1</th>
    <th width="25%">Trial 2</th>
    <th width="25%">Trial 3</th>
    <th width="25%">Range</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="numerical">1</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>    
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>

<div class="main-table-container">
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th width="10%" rowspan="2">Parts</th>
    <th width="90%" colspan="4">Doraemon</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <th width="25%">Trial 1</th>
    <th width="25%">Trial 2</th>
    <th width="25%">Trial 3</th>
    <th width="25%">Range</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="numerical">1</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>    
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>

<div class="main-table-container">
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th width="10%" rowspan="2">Parts</th>
    <th width="90%" colspan="4">Doraemon</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <th width="25%">Trial 1</th>
    <th width="25%">Trial 2</th>
    <th width="25%">Trial 3</th>
    <th width="25%">Range</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="numerical">1</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>
    <td class="numerical">0.000</td>    
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**print.css**

```
body {
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
}

table {
    border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    clear:right;
    margin:1em 0 0 1px;
    font-size:small;
}

th  {
    background-color:#E5ECF9;
    border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 6px;
    text-align:left;
}

td {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
    padding:3px 6px;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
}

th.numerical,
td.numerical {
    text-align:right;
}

.main-title {
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:large ;
}

.header-table-container {
}

.main-table-container {
    float:left;
    margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;
    width:30%;
}
```

Comment: Did you do a test print? Just a hunch, perhaps Firebug doesn't bother with displaying print.css, but your styles may in fact be working?

Comment: Have you actually tried printing it? the `media="print"` means the style will be used *only* for print - not for the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you *changed* the line to `media="print"`... I take it that you do not have a `media="screen"` stylesheet on the page anymore then? Further, you're looking at the page in Firebug, and the styles are gone?
You seem to have some misconception about what you have done...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen"/>
```

means "use the stylesheet `screen.css` whenever displaying this document **on screen**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print"/>
```

means "use the stylesheet `print.css` whenever **printing** this document.

`print` stylesheets only apply when the page is printed. `screen` stylesheets only apply when the document is displayed on screen. If you only have one or the other, your page only has styles either if it's displayed on screen or printed. In your case, the page should look fine printed, but have no styles when viewed on screen. If you want it to be styled in both cases, you need to link two stylesheets, one for screen and one for print.

Having said that, most browsers apply the `screen` stylesheet also when printing, unless you specifically include a `print` stylesheet. I.e., if both stylesheets are identical anyway, you probably don't need to include a separate print stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug will not allow you to debug print CSS. And that would not be accurate anyway as the its ultimately going to the printer, not a browser.

Also note that not all backgrounds will be used even if you declare them in your print CSS. Different browsers will do different things. Some even invert colours for a black background, white text page.

You need to use the print preview button to see how your print styles affect things.

Comment: +1 for the print preview suggestion, save the environment while you test! Also, depending on the complexity of your screen document, the approach I often take is to use the set my media="screen" to media="all" and override any non-compliant/problematic styles in a media="print" sheet. Using media="all" can have detrimental effects on alternative technologies though, if that's an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this way to be nice, that way you dont have to create a new html file

```
function printPage(){
      var w = window.open();

      var headers =  $("#headers").html();
      var field= $("#field1").html();
      var field2= $("#field2").html();

      var html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
        html += '<html lang="en-us">';
        html += '<head><style></style></head>';
        html += "<body>";

        //check to see if they are null so "undefined" doesnt print on the page. <br>s optional, just to give space
        if(headers != null) html += headers + "<br/><br/>";
        if(field != null) html += field + "<br/><br/>";
        if(field2 != null) html += field2 + "<br/><br/>";

        html += "</body>";
        w.document.write(html);
        w.window.print();
        w.document.close();
    };
```