# Nested table-tag within div-tag within table-tag

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following **nasty** layout:

```
<table style="width: 100%; word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="td1">
                <div class="div1">
                    <br>
                    <div style="font-family: calibri,tahoma,arial; font-size: 14px">
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px; padding-top: 4px"
                            id="06C" class="common">
                            <span class="display"><span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline">Reviewer</span></span>
                            <div id="B5E" class="common">
                                &nbsp;</div>
                            <div style="padding-bottom: 2px; margin-top: 5px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;
                                margin-left: 8px; padding-top: 2px" id="4FD" class="common">
                                <span class="display"><span style="text-decoration: underline">Consent</span></span>
                                <div id="692" class="common">
                                    &nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="padding-bottom: 2px; margin-top: 5px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;
                                margin-left: 8px; padding-top: 2px" id="CF6" class="common">
                                <span class="display"><span style="text-decoration: underline">Indication</span></span>
                                <div id="C17" class="common">
                                    &nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="padding-bottom: 2px; margin-top: 5px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;
                                margin-left: 8px; padding-top: 2px" id="59C" class="common">
                                <span class="display"><span style="text-decoration: underline">Location</span></span>
                                <div id="347" class="common">
                                    &nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="div2">
                    <span><span style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold">
                        <br>
                        Completed by:</span></span><br>
                    <span style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 10pt">* Mario Brothers&nbsp;on March 27,
                        2013 10:57 AM CDT
                        <br>
                        * Modified by Dennis Goliath on March 27, 2013 11:17 AM CDT </span>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table style="width: 100%; word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="td2">
                <div class="table2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                    <table style="word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    Result:
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    Orange
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    Date:
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    March 27, 2013 10:57 AM CDT
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    Status:
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    On Going
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    Title:
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    Note
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    Author:
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;
                                    padding-top: 0px">
                                    Mario Brothers&nbsp; on March 27, 2013 10:57 AM CDT
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Yes, it is a table inside a div inside a table...I know...please forgive me :)

I am currently using this as a template for my [print customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971257.aspx).

The issue I've noticed is that the contents of the last table do no print. However, when I remove the wrapper table (and just keep a table inside a div), it works.

I suspect it might be due to how IE (by the way, I am bound to IE) is rendering the table, but don't know for sure.

I would like to understand what is going on, so I thank you for any information you might have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printer Friendly Web Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121147/printer-friendly-web-page)

Comment: Thanks for posting the link. I checked it out, but not sure how it applies to my case

Comment: If I may add, I noticed that if I increase the page setup properties (margins bottom/top) it does seem to work.
  
Also, if I change the page orientation to landscape, it does seem to work also. 

I've spent the last 2 days trying to figure this out and it feels like I am chasing a wild goose at this point, that is, this might be an IE bug or something.